# Strange behavior when filling an object[] with 0s

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to fill my object[] with 0 using this code:

```
 CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 Object[] myrow = new Object[QuotationDG.Columns.Count];
            
 for (int i = 0; i < QuotationDG.Columns.Count; i++ )
 {
       myrow[i] = Convert.ChangeType("0", typeof(object), provider);
       i++;
 }
```

Although I expect the array elements to have values of "0", but the result is that one element has "0" and the next has null, and that proceeds in the whole array. Here's the screenshot from my debugger.

[image]

How can I fix this? and what is causing this?

Comment: remove `i++` from the  loop's body

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing i twice in a row :
one time in the for instruction and another time in the for body.
Delete the i++ instruction right after the column filling and it should work.

```
 CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 Object[] myrow = new Object[QuotationDG.Columns.Count];

 for (int i = 0; i < QuotationDG.Columns.Count; i++ )
 {
       myrow[i] = Convert.ChangeType("0", typeof(object), provider);
       //i++;
 }
```